# Is there a SQL operator like LIKE but not requiring surrounding percent signs?

Tags: mysql, sql

80% of the time I use LIKE in SQL, it is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field LIKE "%foo%"
```

Is there any operator where I can just do:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field CONTAINS "foo"
```

I'm using MySQL.

Comment: What is the reason for your question? Do you have strings that include % or _? If so, you can escape them in order to not see them as wildcards.

It would help to know what you are trying to fix.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for alternatives, don't forget things like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field RLIKE "foo";
```

Though `RLIKE` treats the text as a regular expression so characters like `?` and `*` take on special meaning, among many others.

You can also use [full-text indexes and their corresponding functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) to search:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MATCH (field) AGAINST "foo";
```

The performance of the full-text index is vastly faster than doing a substring search of any sort. A substring `LIKE` requires a painful table scan.

Answer (score 1):

There is also `LOCATE` you can use

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LOCATE('foo',field) > 1
```

Comment: I know that the OP is specifically asking about mysql, but in case others are looking here, in MS SQL the equivalent function is `CHARINDEX`.

Since these are functions that return the location of the substring, which then has to be compared to 0, I would assume that it is much less efficient than using `LIKE`, which is why I asked the OP what issue he is trying to solve.